# Excel Formula to format tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Is there a formula for chaining the colors of a table? I do not want the "normal" (eg red | white | red). What I intend is always that the name of a certain cell is equal, then the background is of color A, when the name of the cell is different then it changes to the color B, when the name changes again then the color returns to be the color A and so on.

Table example.

```
Teste    X    B   A    T   -> color A
Teste    f    s   f    g   -> color A
ALPHA    f    s   f    g   -> color B
ALPHA    g    g   h    r   -> color B
ALPHA    f    s   f    g   -> color B
Beta     G    A   f    g   -> color A
.......
```

The value to compare is from the first column by the value of the first column of the previous row.

It's possible?

Comment: have you tried conditional formatting https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE

Comment: Yes but I did not get what I wanted, can you help me?

Comment: still not sure what/how you want it  `value to compare is from the first column by the value of the first column of the previous row` this i dont get. might update Q With a better example and what you tried

Comment: @krib What he means is look at column A, It's Teste, Teste, ALPHA, ALPHA, ALPHA, Beta. With this he means there is three "groups", Teste, ALPHA and Beta.

Comment: I think you need VBA for this. Is that OK?

Comment: @Andreas Can be vba, as long as it works :)

Comment: Are further columns allowed?

Comment: @vinnie, As long as it works, it can be anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works?

```
Sub test()

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Red = True

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i - 1).Value Then
        While Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i - 1).Value
            If Red Then Range("C" & i - 1 & ":K" & i).Interior.Color = vbRed
            i = i + 1
        Wend
        If Red Then
            Red = False
        Else
            Red = True
        End If
    Else
        If Red Then
            If Red Then Range("C" & i - 1 & ":K" & i - 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
            Red = False
        Else
            Red = True
        End If

    End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: That's right, but the code you have selects the whole line, how do I select only one part of the line, for example, want the red line from column C to K?

Comment: @Kiotto That was not something you mentioned before, but I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create an additional column with the below function.

```
=IFERROR(IF($A1=$A2,$B1,NOT($B1)),TRUE)
```

And you can set up conditional formatting based on this.

[image]